# Double-paged title page

Tags: titles, templates, backgrounds, double-sided

I'm trying to find how I can have a 'double sided' title page in latex, using the TU Delft Template (please see the link below).

Now, a new chapter and thus its title page always starts on the right side.

What I would like, is to add a background image on the left side, like here:

[image]

Who could help me out? I essentially want to have a page preceding the title page in another color... Or I would like to have 2 title pages, but the first one to start on the left. Different logics, same result.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tud-dissertation/tcddkjggskqx

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete but minimal document illustrating the issue. Questions here should be self-contained and not rely on external links. I'm puzzled by your desiderata, though. Suppose a chapter finishes on a left hand page. Do you really want a blank page on the right to follow? I suggest there's a reason that's not a style seen in published books.